# ISO Format Question that is only looking for year, month, date

Tags: r

I am stuck on a question on my homework.
Convert the date "02/07/11" (year/month/day) to ISO format.
I used ISOdate and manually inserted the date but it produced the time as 12:00. I'm not really sure how to format this into ISO as there is no time.

```
d1 <- ymd("02/07/11")
iso <- POSIXct(d1, format="%Y-%m-%d")
Error in POSIXct(d1, format = "%Y-%m-%d") : 
unused argument (format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Read the docs. [`?lubridate::POSIXct`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/posix_utils.html) says two things of note: this function returns an object of length `length=` (its first of two args) using a timezone of `tz=` (second of two args). If you want an ISO9601 format, use `lubridate::format_ISO8601(d1)`. As an alternative, perhaps `base::format(d1, format="%Y-%m-%d")`.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your help. That produced the answer I needed!

Comment: I say this for real, not to pester ... when in doubt when using a function, _especially in `lubridate` and other tidyverse packages_, the docs are often a great resource. This is particularly useful when using new-to-you functions (which if this is your first R semester, is likely "all of them" :-), they generally list the arguments, what they should be, some notes about alternative usage, and sometimes have great examples demonstrating the functions use "in the wild". It is often an expectation that you've read the relevant docs before asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

You want `as.Date`; unlike `lubridate::ymd`, it is already built in and probably what your instructor wants. Since you appear to be new to R, type `?strptime` and you'll find a list of strings, e.g. `%d` for day, that you can use in the `format=` argument. Obviously, here we need `'%y/%m/%d'`, three of these strings, separated by a `/`. Note, how I used a small `%y` since given year has only two digits.

```
> d1 <- as.Date("02/07/11", format='%y/%m/%d')
> d1
[1] "2002-07-11"
```

`ISOdate` is not the right function for the current problem, but might be helpful in the future. The trick is to set the `hour=` argument to midnight, so time output will be omitted.

```
> d2 <- ISOdate(year=2011, month=02, day=07, hour=0)
> d2
[1] "2011-02-07 GMT"
```

The problem with this is, apart that you manually put in the date, that the latter is `"POSIXt"` format, whereas the former is of class `"Date"`.

```
> class(d1)
[1] "Date"

> class(d2)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

The difference is, that `"Date"` incorporates the number of days since "1970-01-01" (the so-called UNIX epoch), whereas `"POSIXt"` counts the seconds.

```
> as.integer(d1)
[1] 11879

> as.integer(d2)
[1] 1297036800
```

If you confuse the two, it can lead to ambiguity in calculations with dates.